# Parsing key - object JSON with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

How can I parse this JSON using GSON?

```
{
    "1" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "images" : [
                {},
                {},
                ...
            ]
        },
        {},
        ...
    ],
    "2" : [
            {},
        {},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

I ran out of ideas how to parse it. I was trying to use map but objects were null.

My classes:

```
public class Root {
    private HashMap<Integer, FirstObject> objects; 
}

public class FirstObject {
    private List<SecondObject> objects;
}

public class SecondObject {
    private int id;
    private List<Image> images;
}

public class Image {
    ...
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're basically not doing anything, so you can't be wrong. Please post your entire code.

Comment: Inside the root class I think that you don't need create a new class, you need to create just public vars of type ArrayList

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then understand that a JSON "array" is a Java List, and a JSON "object" is a Java Map.  A standard JSON parser should be able to produce the Map of Lists of Maps of ... that the above represents, without any direction whatsoever.  You can then pick it apart to your heart's content.  Defining your own objects, for the above structure, is just extra overhead, since the objects would just contain Maps and Lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Root {
    @SerializedName("1")
    @Expose
    private List<Album> _1 = new ArrayList<Album>();

    @SerializedName("2")
    @Expose
    private List<Album> _2 = new ArrayList<Album>();

    ...
}
```

Solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool to generate your Java classes from your JSON. Something like [JSONSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)